# Pass filename from bash to python

Tags: bash, python

Lets say I have 1000 csv files that have random names in a folder `test`. and I have a python script `script.py`. I would like to write a bash script that would pass the name of each file in the folder to `script.py` then run it, therefore the bash script should run `script.py` 1000 times, each time with a different file name, example, first run:

```
with open('records.csv','r') as in_file
```

next run

```
with open('vertigo.csv','r') as in_file
```

I know I could do it in python without the hassle of writing a bash script like so

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('*.csv'):
   # script here
```

But I'm doing some tests therefore I'd like to do it in bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sys.argv[1]` so that the filename is taken from the arguments:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as in_file
```

Then, you can use various methods to pass the filename as an argument. For example, with `find`:

```
find test/ -type f -name '*.csv' -exec /path/to/script.py {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to using `sys.argv` is using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html). Very helpful if you need more command line parameter parsing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import argparse

def main(files):
    for f in files:
        print "Would do something with", f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('file', nargs='+', help='path to the file')
    args_namespace = parser.parse_args()
    args = vars(args_namespace)['file']
    main(args)
```

Running it with having Bash expanding our file argument list:

```
$ ./script.py *.csv
Would do something with file1.csv
Would do something with file2.csv
Would do something with file3.csv
```

And provides built-in help 'for free':

```
$ ./script.py --help
usage: script.py [-h] file [file ...]

positional arguments:
  file        path to the file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to retrieve the filename within the python script for this to work:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.csv; do
    python script.py "$f"
done
```

In a one-liner:

```bsh
for f in *.csv; do python script.py "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending muru's answer a bit:

Why not do it all inside your python script? Transform the script's actions on the files into a function, then run the script with the *directory*  as an argument:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

#--- your original script, transformed into a function
def some_function(file):
    print(file)
#---

# The directory with your .csv files
dr = sys.argv[1]

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    file = dr+"/"+f
    some_function(file)
```

Or a bit shorter:

```py
for f in os.listdir(dr):
    some_function(dr+"/"+f)
```

Or, if the directory also *might* contain other files:

```py
for f in [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".csv")]:
    some_function(dr+"/"+f)
```

Then simply run it with the directory as argument:

```
python3 <script> <directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `sys.argv` as list, providing all individual files as arguments and have your shell (e.g. Bash) expand it for you.

`script.py` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys

def main(files):
    for f in files:
        print "Would do something with", f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = sys.argv[1:]: # slices off the first argument (executable itself)
    main(files)
```

File tree like this:

```
.
├── file1.csv
├── file2.csv
├── file3.csv
└── script.py

0 directories, 4 files
```

Then make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.py
```

Run it with the arguments as expanded by the shell:

```
./script.py *.csv
```

Outputs:

```
Would do something with file1.csv
Would do something with file2.csv
Would do something with file3.csv
```